# Spivak: Proof that if $R$ is $(n+1)$-times diff. on $[a,b]$ and $R^{(k)}(a)=0$ then $\frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^{n+1}}=\frac{R^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

In Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus* is the lemma shown below (used afterward to prove Taylor's Theorem). My question is about a step in the proof of this lemma.

> **Lemma:** Suppose that the function $R$ is $(n+1)$-times differentiable on $[a,b]$ and
>
> $$R^{(k)}(a)=0, \text{ for } k=0,1,2,...,n$$
>
> Then for any $x$ in $(a,b]$ we have
>
> $$\frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^{n+1}}=\frac{R^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}, \text{ for
>  some } t \text{ in } (a,x)\tag{1}$$

**Here is the proof as it appears in the book**

> For $n=0$ this is just the Mean Value Theorem, and we will prove the
> theorem for all $n$ by induction on $n$. To do this we use the Cauchy
> Mean Value Theorem to write
>
> $$\frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^{n+2}}=\frac{R'(z)}{(n+2)(z-a)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n+2}\frac{R'(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}},
>  \text{ for some } z \text{ in } (a,x)$$
>
> and then apply the induction hypothesis to $R'$ *on the interval*
> $[a,z]$ to get
>
> $$\frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^{n+2}}=\frac{1}{n+2}\frac{(R')^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!},
>  \text{ for some } t \text{ in } (a,z)\tag{2}$$
>
> $$=\frac{R^{(n+2)}(t)}{(n+2)!}$$

**My question is:** how do we know that $(R')^{n+1}$ is defined in $(2)$?

**Let me try to go through the proof in more steps.**

For $n=0$ we have

$$\frac{R(x)}{x-a}=\frac{R(x)-R(a)}{x-a}=R'(t)$$

for some $t\in (a,x)$, which is the MVT applied to $R$ on $[a,x]$.

Now assume as our induction hypothesis that $(1)$ is true for some $k$.

First, let's apply Cauchy MVT to the functions $R(x)$ and $g(y)=(y-a)^{k+2}$.

$$\frac{R(x)-R(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{R'(z)}{g'(z)}$$

for some $z\in (a,x)$. Then

$$\frac{R(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{R(x)}{(x-a)^{k+2}}=\frac{R'(z)}{(k+2)(z-a)^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k+2}\frac{R'(z)}{(z-a)^{k+1}}$$

At this point, we are to apply the induction hypothesis to $R'$ on $[a,z]$. In the induction hypothesis, $R$ is assumed to be $(n+1)$-times differentiable. Doesn't this mean that $R'$ is only $n$-times differentiable?

How do we know that $(R')^{n+1}$ is defined in $(2)$?

Comment: Lemma is proved by induction on $n.$ Assuming the formula (call it $F_n$ ) is true for every function $n+1$ differentiable 
function  we have to show that the formula $F_{n+1}$ holds for any $n+2$ differentiable function. That's why $R'$ is $n+1$ differentiable.

Comment: I advise you not to approach Taylor’s theorem that way. There is a much nicer approach that only needs the usual MVT (really, Rollie’s theorem). See the proof of Theorem 1.1 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/TaylorRemainder.pdf.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Your comment should be an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post my comment as an answer encouraged by  @Paul Frost

Lemma is proved by induction on $n.$ Assuming the formula (call it $F_n$) is true for any  $(n+1)$-differentiable function, we have to show that the formula $F_{n+1}$ holds for any $(n+2)$-differentiable function. That's why $R′$ is $ (n+1 )$-differentiable.